# Does the owner of a corporation need a W2 for personal taxes if the Corporation revenue was 0 and didn't make any money?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, form-w-2, corporation

I the owner of a C-Corporation that didn't have any revenue in 2020. I am filing my personal tax returns and was wondering if I need a W2 issued by the Corporation with 0 income or can I just report no income on my returns without a W2?

Just wanted to do this the right way.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Form W-2 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/iw2w3#idm139631568805456), Who must file Form W-2:

> Complete and file Form W-2 for each employee for whom any of the following applies (even if the employee is related to you).
>
> - You withheld any income, social security, or Medicare tax from wages regardless of the amount of wages; or
> - You would have had to withhold income tax if the employee had claimed no more than one withholding allowance (for 2019 or earlier Forms W-4) or had not claimed exemption from withholding on Form W-4; or
> - You paid $600 or more in wages even if you did not withhold any income, social security, or Medicare tax.

Since you did not withhold any tax and you paid less than $600, Form W-2 does not seem to be required.

Comment: And a good thing, because if it were required OP would be past the deadline (now Jan 31) and owe a penalty